# SSH Connection to another port instead of default port no 22 using robot frame work

Tags: selenium, ssh, robotframework

I am using robot framework and sshlibrary to test the ssh login to a remote server.

### Here is how the code look like

open_connection_and_login

```
Open Connection  ${OBR_HOST},port=44000
```

Though robot is trying to make a connection but it is taking port 22 also 
Thats what logs says as below.
Logging into '14.126.66.142,port=44000:22' as 'testk'.

Not sure from where it is picking :22 and appending it.
Can any one please tell what i am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a comma, you have to use multiple spaces as a separator

```
Open Connection    ${OBR_HOST}    port=44000
```

Comma is not a separator in RobotFramework. Now, with comma, you're saying, that your server is `${OBR_HOST},port=44000` where `${OBR_HOST}` is then replaced with the value of the variable. Note, that the "port=44000" is a part of ADDRESS in this case, not the port number. As port number the default value 22 is used.

That is why RobotFramework tries to log into "`14.126.66.142,port=44000`" on port 22.